# my return function does not work inside function in react hooks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

My return function doesn't work inside function, pls help me to solve this problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

    const Category = () => {
        //const[data, useData]=useState([]);
        const FuncMen =() =>{
            var e = document.getElementById("menid");
            var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if(country === "T-shirt"){
                axios.post('http://localhost:8011/api/social/finddatamen',{country})
                .then((res) => {

                     var men = res.data.res.filter(filtereddata => filtereddata.category === "tshirt" ) 
                        console.log('selected value is',men);

                            men &&men.map((val,i)=>{

                            console.log("Tshirtt:",val.Tshirt,"Price:",val.price);
                            return(
                                <div key={i}>
                                    <h1>hello</h1>
                                  {val.Tshirt},
                                  {val.price}
                                  </div>
                            )
                        })


                        })
                    .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('error block called',error);
                })

            }
```

Comment: pls give solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the JSX (div, h1) outside of the `.then`  block, after the `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have FuncMen nested inside Category. I would remove FuncMen and just use something like this if you want to use hooks..

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Category =() =>{
    const [category, setCategory] = useState(undefined)
    var e = document.getElementById("menid");
    var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(country === "T-shirt"){
        axios.post('http://localhost:8011/api/social/finddatamen'{country})
            .then((res) => {
                var men = res.data.res.filter(filtereddatafiltereddata.category=== "tshirt" ) 
                console.log('selected value is',men);
                setCategory(men)

            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error block called',error);
                        })
            }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello {category}</h1>
        </div>
        )
            )
}
```

Then in some other component, use it:

```
render() {
    return (<Category />)
```